# Hide records and ListViews based on permission sets - Possible?

Tags: administration, list-view, permission-sets

1). Is it possible to allow users to see list view based on permission set? `(i.e) Those users who have permission sets assigned to them should only view the ListView.`

2). Is it possible to hide records from other users those who don't have permission Sets?

Actually, Record type permission is given in permission sets.

If yes, please Guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1). Is it possible to allow users to see list view based on permission set? (i.e) Those users who have permission sets assigned to them should only view the ListView.

No.

> 2). Is it possible to hide records from other users those who don't have permission Sets?

No.

---

Both of these fall under the purview of Sharing Settings.

For list view visibility, you can choose a role, role and subordinates, and public groups.

For record visibility, you need to first remove all visibility (set to Private), then create Sharing Rules.